# jQuery selecting/doing something with elements in a class

Tags: jquery

So I thought this would work if I wanted to hide all the content in `<p>` tags when double clicking an element with a class but it's not. I'm assuming it's not reading the `<p>` because it thinks it's part of the class name.

```
    $(".chapter-title").dblclick(function(){
        $(".chapter-title p").hide();
    });
```

Here is the HTML. Kinda long sorry.

```
      <div class="chapter" id="chapter-1">
    <h3 class="chapter-title">Stave I: Marley's Ghost</h3>
    <p>MARLEY was dead: to begin with. There is no doubt whatever about that. The register of his burial was signed by the clergyman, the clerk, the undertaker, and the chief mourner. Scrooge signed it: and Scrooge's name was good upon 'Change, for anything he chose to put his hand to. Old Marley was as dead as a door-nail.</p>
    <p>Mind! I don't mean to say that I know, of my own knowledge, what there is particularly dead about a door-nail. I might have been inclined, myself, to regard a coffin-nail as the deadest piece of ironmongery in the trade. But the wisdom of our ancestors is in the simile; and my unhallowed hands shall not disturb it, or the Country's done for. You will therefore permit me to repeat, emphatically, that Marley was as dead as a door-nail.</p>
    <p>Scrooge knew he was dead? Of course he did. How could it be otherwise? Scrooge and he were partners for I don't know how many years. Scrooge was his sole executor, his sole administrator, his sole assign, his sole residuary legatee, his sole friend, and sole mourner. And even Scrooge was not so dreadfully cut up by the sad event, but that he was an excellent man of business on the very day of the funeral, and solemnised it with an undoubted bargain.</p>
    <p>The mention of Marley's funeral brings me back to the point I started from. There is no doubt that Marley was dead. This must be distinctly understood, or nothing wonderful can come of the story I am going to relate. If we were not perfectly convinced that Hamlet's Father died before the play began, there would be nothing more remarkable in his taking a stroll at night, in an easterly wind, upon his own ramparts, than there would be in any other middle-aged gentleman rashly turning out after dark in a breezy spot&mdash;say Saint Paul's Churchyard for instance&mdash; literally to astonish his son's weak mind.</p>
    <p>Scrooge never painted out Old Marley's name. There it stood, years afterwards, above the warehouse door: Scrooge and Marley. The firm was known as Scrooge and Marley. Sometimes people new to the business called Scrooge Scrooge, and sometimes Marley, but he answered to both names. It was all the same to him.</p>
    <p>Oh! But he was a tight-fisted hand at the grind-stone, Scrooge! a squeezing, wrenching, grasping, scraping, clutching, covetous, old sinner! Hard and sharp as flint, from which no steel had ever struck out generous fire; secret, and self-contained, and solitary as an oyster. The cold within him froze his old features, nipped his pointed nose, shrivelled his cheek, stiffened his gait; made his eyes red, his thin lips blue; and spoke out shrewdly in his grating voice. A frosty rime was on his head, and on his eyebrows, and his wiry chin. He carried his own low temperature always about with him; he iced his office in the dog-days; and didn't thaw it one degree at Christmas.</p>
    <p>External heat and cold had little influence on Scrooge. No warmth could warm, no wintry weather chill him. No wind that blew was bitterer than he, no falling snow was more intent upon its purpose, no pelting rain less open to entreaty. Foul weather didn't know where to have him. The heaviest rain, and snow, and hail, and sleet, could boast of the advantage over him in only one respect. They often "came down" handsomely, and Scrooge never did.</p>
    <p>Nobody ever stopped him in the street to say, with gladsome looks, "My dear Scrooge, how are you? When will you come to see me?" No beggars implored him to bestow a trifle, no children asked him what it was o'clock, no man or woman ever once in all his life inquired the way to such and such a place, of Scrooge. Even the blind men's dogs appeared to know him; and when they saw him coming on, would tug their owners into doorways and up courts; and then would wag their tails as though they said, "No eye at all is better than an evil eye, dark master!"</p>
    <p>But what did Scrooge care! It was the very thing he liked. To edge his way along the crowded paths of life, warning all human sympathy to keep its distance, was what the knowing ones call "nuts" to Scrooge.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

OK wow I just realized I'm calling the wrong class. The P tags aren't in the chapter-title class they are in chapter. My bad guys

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".chapter-title").dblclick(function(){
  $(this).parent().find('p').hide();     
});
```

Use [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get matched p elements from given class selector 'chapter title'. You should hide only p elements next to double clicked title.

**parent()** - Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

**find()** - Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Another way:

```
$(".chapter-title").dblclick(function(){
  $(this).closest('.chapter').find('p').hide();
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/33unm/1/

Comment: alright so this works but i have no idea why. Could you explain it? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: so the reason why parent() is working is because both the chapter-title class and p tags are in a div called chapter?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QkCLb/.

HTML

```
   <div class="chapter-title">
    cat
    <p>barf</p>
    <p>marf</p>
    <p>scarf</p>
</div>
<div class="chapter-title">
    cat
    <p>asdf</p>
    <p>afde</p>
    <p>adsfe</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".chapter-title").dblclick( function() {
   $(this).find('p').hide();
});
```

You might want to post your html, and let us see what's up.

Comment: that works but its not unique to each chapter title class. That hides the p tags for all chapters

Comment: Updated example to only hide p that are descendents of the clicked div.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you are correct. Just drop the 'p' out of the selector. This works. http://jsfiddle.net/64Nz3/

```
 $(".chapter-title").dblclick(function () {
$(".chapter-title").hide();
 });
```

Comment: i only want to hide the <p> tags in the chapter-title class

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $(".chapter-title").dblclick( function() {
      $(this).closest('div').find('p').hide(); 
  });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QkCLb/3/)

Comment: that will hide all of the p tags in the chapter class. It needs to be unique to that chapter. Thanks for trying tho

Answer (score -1):

Ok. This provides a conditional approach using the jquery .prop() method to see if the tagName is a paragraph or not; paragraphs are hidden onclick.

http://jsfiddle.net/64Nz3/1/

```
$(".chapter-title").dblclick(function(){
if($(this).prop("tagName")==="P"){
    $(this).hide();
}
else
{
    //nothing
}

});
```